# Local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, local-storage

I'm trying to get a radio button value and store it in local storage so that I can then access the local storage via the variable...if this doesn't make that much sense to you guys I'm really sorry as I am a beginner in Javascript.

```
 // javascript code (logic.js)//

    console.log("loading...");
    var build= retrievedObject

    if (build===1){

    console.log("Option 1 Remember");   
    };


    if (build===2){
    console.log("Option 2 Remember");   
    };


    if (build===3){
    console.log("Option 3 Remember");   
    };

    window.getValue = function(){
    var vall= document.querySelector("input[name=optionsRadios]:checked").value;
    }

    localStorage.setItem('vall', JSON.stringify(vall));
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('vall');
```

I want to get variable 'vall' to be stored in local storage and then retrieved for later usage.

The html code will get the radio button values and send them to the javascript code (logic.js) via getValue.

```
//HTML Code//

</HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>
<BODY>

<form>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Home" VALUE="1" >Home
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="School" VALUE="2" >School
<INPUT TYPE="radio"  name="optionsRadios" id="Work" VALUE="3" >Work


<center><input type="button" name="send" value="Submit" onclick="getValue();"></center>
</form>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, the local storage does not seem to work.Any help would really be great and a in depth explanation too.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your whole code? When you call `setItem` there is no variable `vall` yet. And the variable is in the function scope. You can't access it this way.

Comment: Hi,could you please elaborate on that.How am I suppose to create the vall variable.I thought I already have it..var val=document...or is that something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript has some issues.

- retrievedObject is not defined when it's referenced on line 2 .
- No need to create a window.getValue function. In addition, all it does is
  assign a value to a locally scoped variable.
- When
  `localStorage.setItem` is called, `vall` doesn't exist, it's out of
  scope.
- `localStorage.getItem('vall')` doesn't work because no value
  has been stored using `vall` as its key.
- You reference jQuery but don't actually use it.

Instead of correcting your code, it's easier to show you how to do it from scratch. I've written you an example of how to use local storage. You can see it on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kLug/3/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Home" value="1" />Home
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="School" value="2" />School
    <input type="radio"  name="optionsRadios" id="Work" value="3" />Work
    <input id="setValue" type="button" name="send" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add click handler to button
    $('#setValue').click(function() {
        // Get the value of the checked radio button
        var valueToSave = $("input[name=optionsRadios]:checked").val();

        if (!valueToSave) {
            alert('Select an option!');
            return;
        }

        // Save the value in local storage        
        localStorage.setItem('vall', valueToSave);
        alert('Saved value: ' + valueToSave);
    });

    // Get the saved value from local storage
    var savedValue = localStorage.getItem('vall');

    if (savedValue) {
        alert('Saved value is: ' + savedValue);

    // If we have a saved value, check the appropriate radio button
        $('input[name=optionsRadios][value=' + savedValue + ']').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am really grateful for your help,however I seem to have a problem when trying to use the saved value to do a logic statement as it says 'savedvalue is not defined'.eg: If (savedValue===1){do something}

Comment: You must declare a variable before using it. `var savedValue = localStorage.getItem('vall'); if (savedValue === 1) { ... }` It's most likely you haven't declared it with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the fact if you were successful in storing the string/object into localStorage.

To retrive the data from localStorage, you need to use `$.parseJSON()` to decode the data into variable/string for your use in your app.

```
var retrievedObject = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('vall'));
```

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

Untested.

```
// javascript code (logic.js)//

    console.log("loading...");
    var vall;
    try {
      vall = localStorage.getItem('vall');
      console.log("read localStorage[vall] = "+vall); 
    } except(e) {
        console.log("got an error reading localstorage "+e);
    }

    window.getValue = function(){
// this function is the only code that has access to the new value of vall
// so it must store it before returning
       var newvall= document.querySelector("input[name=optionsRadios]:checked").value;
       localStorage.setItem('vall',newvall)
    }
```